# Select text in terminal without mouse

Tags: command-line, bash

I have command line in open x-terminal. Part of this command I would like to duplicate. In order to copy I need to do select. How to make select without mouse?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/how-do-i-copy-text-from-my-xterm-without-a-mouse

Comment: Do you mean something like this --> [How to repeat currently typed in parameter on bash console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40128/how-to-repeat-currently-typed-in-parameter-on-bash-console)